# ¿Cómo sobreescribir el método hash para comparar objetos en Java?

Tags: java, hash

Tengo un programa en el que una serie de objetos con su precio se almacenan en un hashtable, pero no sé qué hacer con el método hash. He sobreescrito el método equals. Esta es mi clase:

```
public class Producto {
    private int cod;
    private String nombre;
    private double precio;

    public Producto(int cod, String nombre, double precio) {
        this.cod = cod;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (obj instanceof Producto) {
            Producto tmpProducto = (Producto) obj;

            if (this.cod == tmpProducto.cod
                && this.nombre.equals(tmpProducto.nombre)
                && this.precio == tmpProducto.precio) { 
                return true; 
            } else { 
                return false; 
            }

        } else { 
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias por responder, pero se me presenta otra duda; Tengo este método que compara los objetos pero siempre me devuelve false. Espero que puedan ayudarme. gracias

```
public boolean hayStock(Producto p){
    Hashtable<Producto, Integer> productos = new Hashtable<Producto, Integer>(); 
        if(productos.contains(p)){
            if(productos.get(p) > 0){
                System.out.println("Quedan " +productos.get(p)+ " unidades");
                return true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("No quedan productos");
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("El producto no existe");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tu otra duda debe ir en otra pregunta amigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera más sencilla de sobrescribir la implementación del método `hashCode` es utilizando la clase `java.util.Objects`. Esta ofrece un método llamado `hash(...)` al cual le podemos pasar los atributos de la clase que queremos utilizar para generar el hashCode de esta. Por ejemlpo:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(cod, nombre, precio);
}
```

Y así de simple.

Answer (score 2):

En java los metodos `equals` y `hashcode` van de la mano, no deberias editar uno sin el otro, de lo contrario algunas clases que dependen de su correcta implementacion se comportan de forma erratica (como `Set`, `Map` entre otras)

El contrato general entre `equals` y `hashcode` es que si 2 objetos de una misma clase tienen un hashcode **distinto** entonces equals entre ellos es `false`.

Una forma simple de mantener ese contrato es usar siempre los mismos atributos para determinar la igualdad que para generar su hash. En tu caso estas usando los 3 atributos para determinar su igualdad, por lo que si con ayuda del IDE genero un hashcode usando los mismos 3 atributos obtengo:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 73 * hash + this.cod;
    hash = 73 * hash + (this.nombre != null ? this.nombre.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 73 * hash + (int) (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.precio) ^ (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.precio) >>> 32));
    return hash;
}
```